# comparing datarow value with a string in if

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application which stores a user selected value to the value in my dataset filled datatable. I need to set another column in the table based on this comparison. But the comparison is not working. It always returns false, not entering in the if condition.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsQuestions.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (dr["Data"] == indicater[0])
    {
        dr["IsSelected"] = true;
    }
}
```

`indiactor[0]` is a string array and `dr["data"]` is also of type string but it shows a warning that it needs to a string type.

Comment: afair you cannot compare strings with `==` you need to use `equals`

Comment: `indicator[0]` is a string array and `dr[data]` is a string? are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all string can't compare using == you should use equals method:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsQuestions.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
               if (dr["Data"].tostring().Equals(indicater[0]))
                {
                    dr["IsSelected"] = true;
               }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `DataRow` indexer returns the field at that index as `object` not as `string`.

I would recommend to use the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx)-extension method which also supports nullables:

```
if (dr.Field<String>("Data") == indicater[0]){}
```

... and the [`SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setfield(v=vs.90).aspx) method that also support nullable types:

```
dr.SetField("IsSelected", true);
```

**Update** if `indicater[0]` is really a `string[]` (not a single `string`), how do you want to compare a string with a string[]? If you for example want to check if the array contains this data:

```
if (indicater[0].Contains(dr.Field<String>("Data"))){}
```

That would also explain why it never enters the `if`: because `==` only compares strings by equality, other types which don't have overridden the `==`-operator will compare only the reference. A `string` is never the same reference as a `string[]`. But you don't get a compile time error because you can compare an `object` with everything else.

Comment: @Sayse: i doubt that it's really an array. However, i have added a possible way to check if this data is in the array.

Comment: That doesn't explain why OP's code fails! I'd give +1 if  can see that in your answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: it it's really a `string[]` and not a `string` it would explain why it never enters the `if` ;-)

Comment: I still doubt it is `string[]`. I guess op mean `indiactor` is a `string[]`. So `indicator[0]` is a string. If so, why that comparison fails ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsQuestions.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (dr["Data"].ToString() == indicater[0].ToString())
    {
        Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsSelected"].ToString()) = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it won't compile since you cant assign a value to a boolean

Answer (score 0):

May be useful for you

```
DataRow[] result = table.Select("Id = 1");
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
    if (row[0].Equals(indicater[0]))
    {
       //IsSelected
       row[1]=true;
       Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]);
    }
}
```