# Check if DataRow contains something

Tags: c#

I would like to check if my datarow contains a id and if yes do something. 
what I am doing: `rrGneralRow` is from type `DataRow`

```
if (rrGeneralRow.Equals(1057))
{
    if (!File.Exists(AtargetPath + checksourceFile))
    {
        File.Copy(AsourceFile, AtargetPath + Path.GetFileName(AsourceFile), overwrite: true);
    }
}
if (rrGeneralRow.Equals("1058"))
{
    if (!File.Exists(AtargetPath + checksourceFile))
    {
        File.Copy(AsourceFile, AtargetPath + Path.GetFileName(AsourceFile), overwrite: true);
    }
}
```

So I tried it with "" and without but both does not work.
As you can see in my image the `TREE_CATEGORY` is existing and the number that I am looking for 
[image]

Comment: surely you want rrGeneralRow["TREE_CATEGORY"]==1057? what is that a memory dump of your "rrGeneralRow"?

Comment: @BugFinder if I do that I got Operator == coannot be applied to operands of type object and int

Comment: No  you cant directly do objects, but you arent after objects.. ints, strings.. should work..

Comment: @BugFinder so how can I do that ? if you could post answer to my question ? :)

Comment: Before I can do that, I need an answer to my question - of what is that memory dump of - and preferably what rrGeneralRow is too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing datarow value with a string in if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638438/comparing-datarow-value-with-a-string-in-if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rrGeneralRow` appears to be a `DataRow` type.  If this is the case, you need to interrogate the column name like so:

```
if (rrGeneralRow["TREE_CATEGORY"].ToString().Equals("1057")){
```

Comment: If you convert it to a string you dont need to do .Equals. you can just ==

Comment: Also, depending on the datatype of TREE_CATEGORY, you may want to cast the value of the column to the appropriate datatype.  You could do `(int)rrGeneralRow["TREE_CATEGORY"] == 1057`